# Laravel 5 JSON response to fetch request is nonsense in Firefox

Tags: php, json, firefox, nginx, fetch-api

Using Firefox Nightly 52, when my JS file makes a request with the `fetch` API, the response is garbage.

It is generated by Laravel 5.3 using `return response()->json([...]);`, and sent to the browser using nginx 1.11.4 over HTTP/2.

The response, according to the network tab in the dev tools, is non-sensical. For example:

```
å�älNe?§Z¾tcpí�H-=¼¾a8ÀÎö÷½@Q×(Áò,ðL(¨m"(.âäG{QýÝ8çDµvÙî«ü0=îHù}Úvÿ Ãß"ø\pð=îâuâø¹Ëà#8Zý©³Hkò!?dô³Õ*AD#Ð.hõþ>î¤ô¾}ØJ$ñê;je]¤�¡F$¹¶JS»ýÝ¤þ¸Ëï~÷ãó!.dQQXfX¢³3­¢è?^í\;Ü 'Ù»DPT*&$³
```

When I use the copy as cURL option, I get an error that cURL doesn’t support HTTP/2, i.e. the `--2.0` option. When dropping the option I get a proper response, well-formed JSON with the expected data.

The other difference could be brotli compression. The response sent to firefos is brotli compressed, given firefox says it accepts that in the request headers, whereas cURL does not.

**Edit:** It *is* the brotli compression, if I disable it for `application/json` responses so that nginx falls back to gzip compression my javascript works.

Comment: So Firefox isn't decoding the `br` stream? If so, maybe you're fetching over http?

Comment: Maybe you should be reporting this to the Firefox team as you are using a pre-release version of FF